# Why should we pass files by reference to functions in C++?

Tags: c++, function, file, pointers, reference

What I have is a task of concatenating two files using a function. So what I was trying to do is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

void concatenateFiles(ifstream fileA, ifstream fileB, ofstream fileAB){
   ...
}
```

But I kept having an error I couldn't understand. So I changed this to:

```
...

void concatenateFiles(ifstream &fileA, ifstream &fileB, ofstream &fileAB){
   ...
}
```

And it worked, but I'm not completely sure why. I guess it has something to do with the inability to access the files unless they were passed by reference. Maybe C++ can't make a copy of the file like it makes copies of other variables if not passed by reference? This is as far as I can get with this. This is my first programming course so if you guys could keep the answer as simple as possible it'd be great!

Thanks, Rami.

Comment: Yes, [`std::ifstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) doesn't provide a copy constructor.

Comment: What would it mean to copy a stream?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I still haven't fully understood the 'stream' concept so I can't reason at that level yet :/

Comment: @RamiAwar Then you're asking the wrong question. The right question is "What is a stream?".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz On it! Thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::ifstream` (and other stream classes) does not implement a copy constructor (and rightly so).  In C++11 and later, a compiler's default copy constructor is even explicitly disabled via `= delete`. So you can't pass a `std::ifstream` object to a parameter *by value*, only *by reference*.

Comment: Copy constructor. Got it. Ill look into that thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that because passing by value would require a copy constructor. However, the copy constructor is [explicitly deleted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/istream) at the `std::basic_istream` level<sup>*</sup>

```
basic_istream(const basic_istream& rhs) = delete;
```

Passing by pointer or by reference, on the other hand, does not require copy constructor, so it is allowed.

<sup>*</sup> Prior to introduction of `delete` functionality in C++11 the constructor was `private`.

Comment: It is explicitly deleted only in C++11 and later.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for the note. I keep thinking of C++11 functionality as "the new default" and C++14 as "the new leading edge", but I'm sure there's a lot of C++98 code out there.

Comment: so Im guessing a copy constructor is like a definition of how to copy this file? I haven't come across this term yet. I've very recently started with classes.

Comment: @RamiAwar A copy constructor is a definition of how to copy the object representing your file in memory, not how to copy the file itself.

Comment: Alright! Thank you so much!